# Match with optional positive lookahead

Tags: regex

I've got 2 strings in the format:
`Some_thing_here_1234 Match Me 1` & `1234 Match Me 1_1`

In both cases I want the resultant match to be `1234 Match Me 1`

So far I've got `(?<=^|_)\d{4}\s.+` which works but in the case of string 2 also captures the `_1` at the end. I thought I could use a lookahead at the end with an optional such as `(?<=^|_)\d{4}\s.+(?=_\d{1}$|$)` but it always seems to revert to the second option and so the `_1` gets through.

Any help would be great

Comment: Then exclude the `_`, `(?<=^|_)\d{4}\s[^_]+`, see https://regex101.com/r/4ugzZ3/1. Will there be any other underscores in your expected matches?

Comment: Or only match a single digit after it`(?<=^|_)\d{4}\D*\d` https://regex101.com/r/PfnwLG/2 Or use a non greedy quantifier `(?<=^|_)\d{4}\s.+?(?=(?:_\d)?$)` https://regex101.com/r/5PsmDl/1

Comment: Thanks both. @WiktorStribiżew that was it. Kivking myself now :-( Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<=^|_)\d{4}\s[^_]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ugzZ3/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=^|_)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with either start of string or a `_` char (equal to `(?<![^_])`)
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[^_]+` - one or more chars other than `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second pattern `(?<=^|_)\d{4}\s.+(?=_\d{1}$|$)` is greedy and at the end of the string the second alternative `|$` will match so you will keep matching the whole line.

Note that you can omit `{1}`

If you want to use an optional part in the lookahad, you can make the match non greedy and optionally match `:_\d` in the lookahead followed by the end of the string.

```
(?<=^|_)\d{4}\s.+?(?=(?:_\d)?$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PsmDl/1).